# callback python function from C++ , object destructed

Tags: python, c++, boost

i execute a section of python code to generate C++ object and callback a python function , then return this object to python , why object destructed ?

i used boost python to wrap my C++ program and create a dialog from python .then when clicked a button , callback a python function ,return this object pointer to this function , but the object member data seems all cleared

```
class MyObj
{
public:
   OtherThing();
   ConnectFunc(boost::python::object callbackfun){m_pyCallbackFunc=callbackfun;}
   //some operation will call below function 
   DoSomething(){m_pyCallbackFunc(this)}
private:
   boost::python::object m_pyCallbackfunc;
   vector<int> m_vecData;
}

def callback(myobject):
   #call my object functions again 
   myobject.Otherthing()

//first generate C++ object by python ,such as 
obj=MyObj
obj.ConnectFunc(callback)....
```

everything goes well , but when execute OtherThing()function , the member data
m_vecData has been cleared . i found when called python function "callback" ,
MyObj will call destruction function , so data has been cleared

can anybody help me how to avoid it , i want to keep it ? or anybody gives me good idea

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
DoSomething(){m_pyCallbackFunc(this)}
```

Your `m_pyCallbackFunc` receives a new proxy object from a copy of this, meaning that the object it receives **is not** the object `DoSomething` received. Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    boost::python::object bar()
    {
        return boost::python::object(boost::python::ptr(this));
    }
};
```

That you exported as follow:

```
boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def(
        "bar",
        &Foo::bar
    );
```

It would be safe to assume `foo.bar()` would returns `foo` but that is not the case. The following would throw an assertion error:

```
foo = Foo()
assert foo is foo.bar()
```

Because what was returned was a new proxy object. If you want to pass the same object back to Python, you must either declare your class such as Boost know it [has back references](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/v2/has_back_reference.html), or my favourite; declare your method as static and extract your instance:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static boost::python::object bar(boost::python::object self)
    {
        Foo &pSelf = boost::python::extract<Foo &>(self);
        return self;
    }
};
```

Now the code above would no longer raise an assertion error because the returned object is the same that was received. Basically, your destructor was being called because the copy that was made by the proxy object was going out of scope and deallocated.